# How to stop sound in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

When playing a sound using e.g:

```
sound(x,fs);
```

I sometimes by accident play the wrong one. If x is of substantial length, I currently try to wait until the sound has completed. Any suggestions on how to "abort" the playback? I've already tried

```
sound(mute,fs); % Mute is a short vector containing all zeroes
```

But that didn't work. I'm using Windows by the way.

**UPDATE:**
The following solution proposed by kigurai seems to do the trick:

```
sound(x,fs); % Start the audio
```

Now kill audio by

```
clear playsnd
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried ctrl-c but that didn't work?

Comment: Thanks! `clear playsnd` didn't work for me in R2013a, however, `clear sound` did, so still appreciate the hint :)

Comment: `clear sound` is good, but `clear all` is a superset of all clears and hence also works

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Never used "sound()" but when I have played audio using wavplay(..., ..., 'async') I can stop the sound by issuing

```
clear playsnd
```

Maybe that works with sound() as well?
Note: This is when playing asynchronously. For synchronous playback I assume that CTRL-C should break it, but I had issues with wavplay() last time I tried that.

Comment: Just tried this: started audio using "sound()" and issuing clear playsnd stop the audio. Nice!

Comment: if you played many consecutive sounds it will only stop the last one

Answer (score 60):

Try this command Definitely works !!

clear sound

Comment: If you have a variable called `sound` you should enter this command twice

Comment: Worked in 2017a!

Comment: Is there even a `sound` object in workspace? Worked BTW :)

Answer (score 28):

[Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.co.kr/support/solutions/en/data/1-BC4R6Y/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-BC4R6Y) says (and this applies to `sound` as well),

> There is no function in MATLAB that
>   can pause or stop audio playback once
>   initiated by WAVPLAY. Instead of using
>   WAVPLAY, an alternative is to create
>   an AUDIOPLAYER object. This type of
>   object has methods which allow
>   pausing, resuming and stopping the
>   audio playback. For example:

```
player = audioplayer(Y, Fs)

% start the playback
play(player);

% pause the playback
pause(player);

% resume the playback
resume(player)

% stop the playback
stop(player)
```

Comment: Damn, I was 8 sec too late ;)

Comment: Lol, it's hilarious how everyone seems to have woken up at answered this question at around 1000 EST :)

Comment: Just as I hit the button to post my answer, I got the orange banner saying other answers were posted. =D

Comment: Indeed :) more than 30 minutes without any answer, and then, suddenly, 3 at almost the same time :D And you really do think...

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but I wanted to try out the suggested solution before selecting an answer. The solution jacob proposes works, and thank you for the suggestion. However, the solution suggested by kigurai I think is more appropriate for the question: Kill sound(). So I'm selecting kigurai's response as answer to my question. Thanks again!

Comment: This does not work within a Matlab callback function

Comment: I find this the most principled answer that worked in all my different versions of matlab. Unlike clear sound

Answer (score 7):

Use the audioplayer object instead - it gives you the full control on what you do with the sound. I.e:

```
player = audioplayer(x, fs);
play(player)   % start the player
stop(player)   % stop whenever you like...
```

Audioplayer has a lot of other useful stuff:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/audioplayer.html