# MATLAB: Stopping a sound playing

Tags: matlab, audio

I am using a MATLAB function to initiate a sound. This function is as follows:

```
function playTone (duration, toneFreq)
% Generate a tone

global player; % as a global variable, sound will continue to play after the function has ended.
samplesPerSecond = 44100; % the bit rate of the tone
y = sin(linspace(0, duration * toneFreq * 2 * pi, round(duration * samplesPerSecond))); % the equation of the sound wave
player = audioplayer(y, samplesPerSecond); % create an audio object from the sound wave at the specified bit rate
play(player); % play the audio, blocking control until the sound completes
```

I would like to be able to stop the sound on request. I cannot use:

```
clear playsnd;
```

since I have instigated the sound using the audioplayer() function (not the sound() function).

I also cannot use:

```
stop(player);
```

because I am trying to stop the sound from a parent function ("??? Undefined function or variable 'player'.")

I have had to set my function up as above since I need to be able to produce a tone from a subfunction and I cannot use the sound() function since I occasionally get the error message "Cannot register sound window". The 'player' variable is set as global to ensure the sound continues to play after the function completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you modify the function so that it returns the handle for the player?

```
function player = playTone (duration, toneFreq)
% Generate a tone

global player; % as a global variable, sound will continue to play after the function has ended.
samplesPerSecond = 44100; % the bit rate of the tone
y = sin(linspace(0, duration * toneFreq * 2 * pi, round(duration * samplesPerSecond))); % the equation of the sound wave
player = audioplayer(y, samplesPerSecond); % create an audio object from the sound wave at the specified bit rate
play(player); % play the audio
```

Then you can stop it later using `stop(player)`.

Similar question: [How to stop sound in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742268/how-to-stop-sound-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare that `player` is a global variable wherever you want to use it, including where you want to stop the player:

```
global player;
stop(player);
```

Using global variables is however frowned upon. so I would recommend that you use Geoff's suggestion, and return the handle.