# stop playing a wav file in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, audio, user-interface

I created a GUI in MATLAB to analyze piano songs. My GUI basically has a load, play and stop button.

I load the file using the code

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile({'*.wav'},'Load Wav File');
[x,Fs] = wavread([PathName '/' FileName]);
handles.fileLoaded = 1;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

This is the code I used to play the song

```
if (handles.fileLoaded==1)
    sound(handles.x, handles.Fs);
end
```

After this, I'm not sure how I can stop the song, so that every time i test the GUI I wouldn't have to keep listening to the whole song... Any suggestions??
Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `audioplayer`

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile({'*.wav'},'Load Wav File');
[x,Fs] = wavread([PathName '/' FileName]);
player=audioplayer(x,Fs); 
% start the playback
play(player);
% pause the playback
pause(player);
% resume the playback
resume(player)
% stop the playback
stop(player)
```

You can use audioplayer class methods in your buttons code.
You can look this link too [How to stop sound in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742268/how-to-stop-sound-in-matlab)

Comment: Thank you. `clear playsnd` in the link you've mentioned seemed to do the trick :)