# How can I build the stop sound function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio

Can anybody tell me how can I build the stop function of sound in Matlab or even give a link? not the ready function in Matlab widgets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop sound in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742268/how-to-stop-sound-in-matlab)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I don't want to use the ready function of the Matlab widgets, I need to build it myself @marsei

Comment: Closed vote retracted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's way of dealing with sounds is based on `audioplayer` which is an object (in the object-oriented programming sense - not a widget then!). You can have a look at the associated script by typing

> edit audioplayer

in the Matlab's command window and study the code. You will see the `stop` method written in there.